# Schwarz inequality and uniform converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

> Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}$$. Show that for $x\ne 0$ $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to some $f$.

So the solution suggests the Schwarz inequality, yielding:

$$\left|f_n(x)\right| \le \frac{\left|x\right|}{2\sqrt n \left|x\right|} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$$

How did the Schwarz inequality applied here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality thus:

$$2\sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert = \lvert \langle (1,\sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert), (\sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert,1)\rangle\rvert \leqslant \lVert (1,\sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert)\rVert_2\cdot \lVert (\sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert,1)\rVert_2 = 1 + n\lvert x\rvert^2.$$

It is, in my opinion, however more immediate to use $0 \leqslant (a-b)^2$, from which $2ab \leqslant a^2 + b^2$ follows, for $a = 1$ and $b = \sqrt{n}\lvert x\rvert$.